Bayesian analysis of alien visitation
The gain in odds that aliens are visiting Earth (A) due to $n$ independent reports of a close encounter (C) is given by:
$$\frac{\rm Odds(A|C^n)}{\rm Odds(A)}=\left[\frac{\rm Prob(C|A)}{\rm Prob(C|\bar A)}\right]^n.$$
Let us assume that we have good cases such that an alien explanation ($a$) is as likely as a non-alien explanation ($\bar a$):
$$\rm Prob(C\ \&\ a) = Prob(C\ \&\ \bar a).$$
Therefore
$$\rm \frac{Prob(C|A)}{Prob(C|\bar A)}=\frac{Prob(C\ \&\ \bar a)+Prob(C\ \&\ a)}{Prob(C\ \&\ \bar a)}=2.$$
Thus the gain in odds that aliens are visiting Earth is given by
$$\frac{\rm Odds(A|C^n)}{\rm Odds(A)}=2^n.$$
Accordingly we only need $50$ good cases of close encounters to raise the odds by a factor of $10^{15}$ which will overpower any reasonable prior bias against alien visitation.
Is this analysis correct?
Preston Dennett has compiled many close encounter cases from around the world.
EyesOnCinema has many firsthand witness testimonies of close encounters.

Funny question raising another classical question : taking into account (numerically ?) the reliability of testimonies... :)
